# What is [i-1] doing is this program? C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I just finished an assignment and got it to work, but I am unsure as to what what the `[i-1]` is doing in the program. Is it telling the program what number to stop at based on the user input? How is it interacting with the user input and array?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int x;
    int y;

    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;

    string nums[] = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };

    for (int i = x; i <= y; i++) {

        if (i <= 9) {
            cout << nums[i-1] << endl;
        }
        else if (i > 9 && i % 2 == 0) {
            cout << "even" << endl;
        }
        else if (i > 9 && i % 2 != 0) {
            cout << "odd" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program prints out a range of numbers based on two user `int` inputs, with the output spelling the numbers out 1-9, and anything over 9 just prints in order as even or odd.

Comment: Review whatever learning materials you're using and take a look at the section on arrays. `nums` is an array. `nums[i-1]` refers to the `i-1`th element of `nums`.

Comment: Check what happens, when `0` is given as input for `x`.

Comment: Try replacing it with `[i]`, compile and run the program, and enter something other than 9. Observe what happens.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's the second most-evil advise after the infamous "type format C: and see what happens" :-)

Comment: Strong recommendation: Don't program C++ by guess. It very rarely rewards. Before you make a change, you need to have a pretty good, evidence-based idea of what'll happen and what the side effects will be. If you're borrowing other people's code, and don't know what a piece of code in it does, isolate it and run some experiments. You'll learn new tricks that way and can safely put them in your programming arsenal. You'll also mitigate bits of nasty where the code does something nefarious that wasn't advertised.

Comment: Change your `nums` array so that "zero" is the first entry.  This will make your indices match the strings better, since arrays are zero based indexed.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ arrays start at the index 0 not 1, thus in order to get the first element of the array `string nums[]` you need to select `nums[0]`. However your input is in the range 1 - 9 but the first entry in the nums array represents `one`. So to get the word `one` after the user entered 1 you need to select `nums[0]`
or `nums[i - 1]` with `i = 1`

Comment: That makes more sense! I kind of assumed that's what it was doing but needed some more clarification. This is from an online class I'm taking for school so I'm kinda figuring a lot of this stuff out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you can make life easier and simpler by placing a stub or unused value in the first array position:

```
std::string    nums[] =
    {"zero", "one", "two", "three",
     "four", "five", "six", "seven",
     "eight", "nine"};
//...
if (i <= 9)
{
    std::cout << nums[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Adding the "zero" string as the first element, the strings are now better aligned in the array.

Comment: I didn't even think of that. Doing that worked when getting rid of the i-1. I will have to remember that for the future.